# Socket data type giving error even after importing java.net.*;

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, types, boolean

I was using the below code for Socket connection in Java and it is giving an error that Socket data type doesn't exist even after importing java.net.*; But when I declare the Socket variable con, above the try block it says that boolean variable and Socket variable don't match. The coding is as follows. Please advise.

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*



    public class DTServer {
    public static void main (String argv[]) {
    int dayTimePort = 13;
    try {
    ServerSocket dtserver = new ServerSocket (dayTimePort);
    while (Socket con = dtserver.accept ()) {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter (con.getOutputStream (), true);
    Date now = new Date ();
    out.println (now.toString ());
    con.close ();
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the problem:

```
while (Socket con = dtserver.accept ())
```

The `while` statement needs a `boolean` condition - and a `Socket` isn't a `boolean`. (And you can't declare a variable in a `while` condition either...)

You probably want:

```
while (true) {
    Socket con = dtserver.accept();
    ...
}
```

Of course, if you have some other condition you want to use, put that instead of `true`. For example, you might want some way of shutting down the server gracefully.

Comment: your answer seems to work, but what about declaring Socket outside the while and still using the same code inside while?I have seen some examples like that in various net sites. But that also doesn't seem to work. Why is that? Doesn't ServerSocket.accept() return the socket number?

Comment: @user2625772: It depends on what you do with it - "doesn't seem to work" doesn't tell us much about what you're doing or what problems you're encountering. And no, `ServerSocket.accept` doesn't return a socket number - it returns a `Socket` reference. That much is clear from the documentation, I'd expect.

Comment: well, the error I am getting is that boolean value cannot be converted to Socket. But as you said, since ServerSocket.accept return a Socket reference, why is it saying that Boolean cannot be converted to Socket?

Comment: @user2625772: Without seeing the code, it would be pure guesswork. I suggest you post this as a new question, given that I've answered your original one.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
while(Socket con = dtserver.accept ())
```

to

```
Socket con = null;
while(true){
      con = dtserver.accept ();
}
```

Comment: Nope, that's still not going to compile.

Comment: What's the benefit to declaring the variable outside the loop? Or giving it an initial value which is never going to be read?